# Looks like COM object is created, but JScript fails to get a reference

Tags: c++, dll, com, jscript

I'm using the following code to create a COM component that I have developed and registered.

```
var mycom = new ActiveXObject("Mirabilis.ComponentServices.1");

mycom.SetFirstNumber(5);
mycom.SetSecondNumber(3);
```

The first line runs fine, while if I alter the **ProgID** (that is, the string passed to **ActiveXObject**) I get the message *Automation server can't create object*. This suggests that at least the basics of the registration mechanism are working properly.

I integrated some logging calls into the DLL. When I run the script I get the proof into the log file that both this call to **QueryInterface**:

```
STDAPI DllGetClassObject(
    const CLSID &clsid,
    const IID &iid,
    void **ppv)
{
    ...
        CAddFactory *pAddFact = new CAddFactory;
        ...
        HRESULT hr = pAddFact->QueryInterface(iid, ppv);

        if (hr == S_OK)
            writeToLogFile("Class QueryInterface returned S_OK");
        else
            writeToLogFile("Class QueryInterface failed");

        return hr;
    ...
}
```

and this one:

```
HRESULT __stdcall CAddFactory::CreateInstance(
    IUnknown *pUnknownOuter,
    const IID &iid,
    void **ppv)
{
    ...
        CAddObj *pObject = new CAddObj;
        ...
        HRESULT hr = pObject->QueryInterface(iid, ppv);

        if (hr == S_OK)
            writeToLogFile("Object QueryInterface returned S_OK");
        else
            writeToLogFile("Object QueryInterface failed");

        return hr;
    ...
}
```

return **S_OK**. However, when JScript gets to line 3 of the script, I get the following error message:

```
'mycom' is null or not an object
```

Why is this happening? It looks like JScript should be able to obtain a reference.

**Some attempts I made**

- I tried to return **S_FALSE** from **DllCanUnloadNow** to be sure that the DLL will not be unloaded, just in case, but with no luck.

**Update**

I should review some COM/OLE/ActiveX theory... By adding logging calls I found out that JScript most likely is able to get a reference to the COM object, and makes a total of 6 **QueryInterface** calls to it, and they *all fail*. Among these there is probably an attempt to retrieve [**IDispatch**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDispatch), which is mandatory for objects which are to be used by scripting languages. Do you think implementing **IDispatch** is all that I need to make it work?

Comment: Javascript (and VBScript) can only use "automation" interfaces, or IDispatch interfaces yes. So, you need to implement these at least, but it's easier with a library such as ATL (if you're a Visual Studio user)

Comment: If you've created your COM interface in MIDL, you can probably make it a dual interface, this makes the IDispatch part easy enough to implement (you can call directly `DispGetIdsOfNames`, `DispInvoke` etc. using your own type info from the type library)

Comment: You need `IDispatch` + valid type information/library, or you need `IDispatchEx` instead. JScript needs to discover your available methods/properties somehow and you need to make a step towards this.